# Como enviar los datos de un XML(yo soy el cliente) hacia un WDSL

Tags: xml, oracle, soap, wsdl

Saludos, tengo una BD Oracle que crea un arhivo XML que contiene datos que necesito se puedan enviar o consumir hacia un WSDL. Ya tengo el XML listo, pero lo que no logro saber es como enviar el archivo o la informacion.

Comment: Debes tener claro que es lo que quieres hacer, en que lenguaje quieres enviar la información, etc, ejemplo: con `PHP` puedes usar [**`SoapClient`**](http://php.net/manual/es/class.soapclient.php), o puedes usar esta herramienta llamada [**SoapUI**](https://www.soapui.org/downloads/soapui.html)

Comment: Tu pregunta probablemente pueda ser cerrada por ser demasiado amplia, por lo que te recomiendo que te des el **[tour]** y también revises la zona de **[ask]**

Comment: puedes usar postman inclusive para pruebas de xml

Comment: Kevin ha realizado la pregunta correctamente. El tiene un archivo XML y quiere enviarlo como respuesta a un WEB SERVER que seguramente pide AUTENTICACION con CERTIFICADO y CLAVE.
Sin alguien publica el código de autenticación en PHP ya seria eso una gran ayuda.